# 2 Google App Engine Datastore updates

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have 2 GAE apps running (GAE1 and GAE2). I have to update the datastore of GAE2 from GAE1. How can I achieve this in Java? Does GAE provide any APIs for cross GAE datastore updates?

Note:
I tried making a PUT request through the browser, by enabling CORS on the source and destination GAEs. Unfortunately CORS works only for GET and HEAD.

Comment: 1. CORS works for PUT and POST also. 2. take a look at datastore java client - https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/

Answer (score 3):

This issue is fixed in the following way, (Note my requirement is I should not use Remote API from GAE.)

1. Open an URL in the destination GAE allow this url alone, if it contains a secure request header.

For example:

```
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        if (requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath().contains("intgr")
    }
```

2. Check for the request header that you pass, if it is present in the destination GAE.
3. Write your REST service in this url path /intgr and send back the response to the Source GAE.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [Cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/) mentioned previously, you can also use the [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#configuring_remote_api_on_an_app_engine_client) to access services across different App Engine applications including Datastore.